# Convert momentary button to toggle switch?

Tags: power, button

I have this simple circuit (existing, not mine) that you toggle on and off with a simple push button and when you power it off and back on it stays off unless the button is pressed. I want to set this device on a timer but in doing so it never comes back on once the power has been cut. Is there a way to easily change the push button to a switch instead so if the power is killed it comes back on? Maybe another way to accomplish the same end goal?

I can't just hardwire the power as it's powering a PWM pump so I need to power up the circuit.

It's a kids toy, basically a little garden and the power turns on the light/pump.

[image]

Comment: What does your circuit look like?

Comment: what happens if you power it up with the power button permanently held down?

Comment: If i power it up with the button pressed it starts up off but turns on when I release it.

Comment: I'm  a little confused. Are there two switches? One for power on/off (main supply enabled or disabled) and a momentary that's needed to be used once the main supply has been turned on? In short, are there TWO switches involved here? Or just one used in a way I still don't understand?

Comment: Just one, push on/off. I unplugged it to simulate if I put a timer on inline with the power.

Comment: Thats a PCB what does the circuit look like? Can you get a schematic of the portion you want to redesign, most people here are not likely to reverse engineer the circuit for you.

Comment: "If i power it up with the button pressed it starts up off but turns on when I release it."  that sounds like some kind of sequencing circuit could work, if you can figure out how to electrically simulate a button push (by reverse engineering the button circuit) or by using one relay for power and another to replace the button.  Simulate button push, activate power, wait, simulate button release...